Azure AD OIDC authentication on a Blazor 8 web app using Microsoft.Identity.Web doesn't produce refresh token
I have setup a Blazor 8 web app with Azure AD authentication using the Microsoft.Identity.Web (AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp from Microsoft.Identity.Web).
It all works fine as I get the access token for the web app authentication/authorization and I also use that for the Web API bearer token. The problem comes to the lack of refresh token. I have the following in the scope : offline_access, profile and openid. I don't however, get the refresh token. Due to the lack of refresh token, I am not able to refresh the access token after it expires.
I get the access token with the code below
 options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
 {
    accessToken = context.TokenEndpointResponse!.AccessToken;
 }

I was expecting the refresh token with a code like
context.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token"); but I get null.
Any ideas what could the potential reasons be for not getting the refresh tokens please?

In your code snippet, you are now using MSAL which has the benefit to Maintains a token cache for you and handles token refreshes when they're close to expiring, so that we don't require a refresh token, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-overview

By the way, the refresh token is obtained in auth code flow when generating access token, but when this event options.Events.OnTokenValidated is triggerred, it's not generating an access token that time, I had a test in my side with your code, when I running my app and login successfully, this event is triggered, but I can only get id token in context.TokenEndpointResponse, TokenEndpointResponse do have properties for access token and refresh token, but they are all null.

Thanks Tiny - In the auth code flow, I am able to get the access token as described above. I understand that there is a token cache but that is more for the app token rather than access as user. Isn't it?

Hi Tenacious, I'm sorry that  I can't understand "there is a token cache but that is more for the app token rather than access as user" well. Per my understanding, when we are trying to obtain access token, we are trying to use it to access an API. AAD has 2 kinds of access token, one is on behalf of user(require delegated API permission), another is on behalf of application(require application API permission). But refresh token is only available for auth code flow which is used for generating delegated access token. Therefore, even ifwe generate token via TokenAcquisition, it's for user too

I have tried using GetAccessTokenForUserAsync directly and that gave me "No Account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent" error. Have you used GetAccessTokenForUserAsync successfully?

Hi, pls open private window or visit your website in another browser to make sure you need to sign in again, then I trust  the exception would disappear. I always meet this exception, it's because the login status is remembered by the browser.

OK. I managed to solve this one.
My problem was the exact one highlighted at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1803.
The resolution was found at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/customization#how-to-query-microsoft-graph-on-token-validated

You don't need to handle the refresh tokens, you can configure Microsoft.Identity.Web to enable token acquisition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore#startupcs.
Example from the docs:
  services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]{"user.read" })
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Then you can use either the Graph client directly (if calling MS Graph API), or inject IDownstreamApi (and make calls through it), or inject ITokenAcquisition (get tokens manually).
It'll handle token refresh if needed.
Note in the samples it uses in-memory token caches,
which will be cleared if your server process restarts and also will differ across instances if running in a server farm.
I would recommend checking how to configure a persistent token cache: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/token-cache-serialization.
You can for example utilize IDistributedCache.

Thanks juunas - ITokenAcquisition works well when a token has to be acquired for the App and I am using that for MS Graph client separately. I am passing a JWT bearer token after OIDC user authententication for invoking the Web Api which is secure. This is in the request header through the HttpClient. This works well until the token expires. Can I use ITokenAcquisition for the user token? I get "No Account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent" when I call GetAccessTokenForUserAsync
